# Index of current element in Haskell list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Is there any way that I can know the index of current element that x is pointing to in the code below:

```
funcName k = [<current_index_here> | x <- list, x == k]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

Index each element with an integer using `zip`:

```
funcName k = [if i == 2 then ... else ... | (i,x) <- zip [0..] list, x == k]
```

Comment: @SwapnilB. as an additional comment I want to add that sometimes it's better to use `ilist` package if you do a lot of work with indexes. It defines a lot of indexed versions of functions: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this with the `ilist` library (a very useful library):

```
import Data.List.Index 
> indexed [i*i | i <- [7,6,5]]
[(0,49),(1,36),(2,25)]
```

Not sure it's exactly what you want but that should be close I believe.